# How to display each key's values in a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The basic idea is pretty simple. Let's begin with the **JavaScript object**:

```
apps = {
    app1:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Unnamed",
        "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
    ],
    app2:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Another one!",
        "Cool!"
    ],
}
```

I have the following variables set up already to help me with my case:

> `_Meta` ["app1", "app2"]
> `_Ammount` 2

Now, what I need to do is create a `<div>` with its ID attribute set to key's name (e.g. "**app1**", or `_Meta[0]`) then in this `<div>` add a new div element with its `class` attribute set to "window-header" and in this div write in the following:
`<i class="ci-pro {line 1 of they key's value}"></i> {line 2 of the key's value}`. And finally, a new **div** with line 3 of the key's value as content.
**Example:**

```
<div id="app1">
    <div class="window-header"><i class="ci-pro ci-extension"></i> Unnamed</div>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the same goes for all other keys.

### What I tried?

**JavaScript:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < _Ammount; i++) {
    var tmp = meta[i];
    console.log(apps.tmp); //returns: undefined, undefined
}
//and also...
for (var i = 0; i < _Ammount; i++) {
    var tmp = meta[i];
    console.log(apps + "." + tmp); //returns: [object Object].app1, [object Object].app2
}
```

And everything else is using jQuery `append` to create the elements and fill in the needed infrmation.

### So, how do you make the `for` return an object with each key's values?

My mind is obfuscated at its maximum levels, so any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out Object.keys()... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: `apps[ tmp ]` not `apps+"."+tmp` or `apps.tmp`. The latter is accessing the property literally named tmp, and the other is just making a string, not using the value of `tmp` as a accessor to `apps`. Look at [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a for...in loop

```js
apps = {
    app1:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Unnamed",
        "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
    ],
    app2:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Another one!",
        "Cool!"
    ]
}

for(let key in apps){
    console.log(key, apps[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apps = {
    app1:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Unnamed",
        "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
    ],
    app2:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Another one!",
        "Cool!"
    ],
};

for(var key1 in apps) {
    for(var key2 in apps[key1]) {
        console.log('key2', key2, 'value:', apps[key1][key2]);  
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj={a:0, b:1, c:2}

for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(obj[key])
}
```

this iterates through keys in the object. the key can be called anything and then you access it by `obj[key]`

Answer (score 0):

I would probably iterate over the [object keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) using a [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop. As a pointer I would suggest using an object for your app description fields rather than piling them into arrays, having the key to reference there would make maintainability a bit easier down the road.

```
apps = {
    app1:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Unnamed",
        "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
    ],
    app2:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Another one!",
        "Cool!"
    ],
};

let container = document.querySelector(/*containing element*/);
Object.keys(apps).forEach(key => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = key;

    let header = document.createElement('div');
    header.className = 'window-header';
    header.innerHTML = `<i class="ci-pro ${apps[key][0]}"></i>${apps[key][1]}`;

    let hello = document.createElement('div');
    hello.innerHTML = `<h1>${apps[key][3]}</h1>`;

    div.appendChild(header);
    div.appendCheild(hello);
    container.appendChild(div);
});
```